# SQL Extract string between two comma for a given string and split in key value pair of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've the following values in one field concatenated(I've splitted them)

```
--,\r\n  \"Indie_163\": \"\",
--,\r\n  \"Pop_197\": null,
--,\r\n  \"Mgr_206\": \"Mark Timberland\",
--,\r\n  \"Date_225\": \"02/28/2019\"
--,\r\n  \"Fees_200\": \"57500\",
```

Actual Value in field:

```
 {\"Indie_163\": \"\","Pop_197\": null,\r\n  \"Mgr_206\": \"Mark Timberland\",\r\n  \"Date_225\": \"02/28/2019\",\r\n  \"Fees_200\": \"57500\"})
```

Need to split them in 5 Key Pair values columns:

```
Indie_Key | Indie_Val | Pop_Key | Pop_Val | Mgr_Key | Mgr_Val | Date_Key | Date_Val | Fees_Key | Fees_Val
```

It should populate the Keys and value as (Blank '', null, or values coming after split (:) inside the double quotes)

Note: Columns - 'Indie_', 'Pop_', 'Mgr_', 'Date_', 'Fees_' are fixed string the suffix numbers can change

Comment: Can you please fix the formating? Also, would you please tag your question with the RDBMS that you are using: oracle, mysql, sql-server, ...?

Comment: @GMB: I am not good at formatting at SOF (StackOverFlow) :(

Comment: Do you really have all these escaped quotes (`\"`) and carriage returns (`\r\n`) within the field value?

Comment: @GMB: I do have them

Comment: What have you tried so far? Asking on how to do something, without showing us your efforts is not what SO is about

Comment: It looks like badly json encoded value. `replace(replace(x, '\"', '"'), '\r\n', '')` will convert the string to valid json. Could you use SQL Server 2016 (includes json support). How many string do you have to convert ? is it a one shot operation ?

Comment: @Fandango68: I tried was this:

SELECT 
   
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(x, CHARINDEX('\"Indie_163', x), CHARINDEX(',', SUBSTRING(x,CHARINDEX('\"Indie_163', x),  LEN(x)))), '\"', ''), ': ', ''), ',', '')    AS 'Indie_Key',
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(x, CHARINDEX('\"Indie_163', x), CHARINDEX(',', SUBSTRING(x,CHARINDEX('\"Indie_163', x),  LEN(x)))), '\"', ''), ': ', ''), ',', '')    AS 'Indie_Val'

FROM tblName
Had to split using ':'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data looks like badly encoded json value. You can fix these by using `replace(replace(x, '\"', '"'), '\r\n', '')`

The `OPENJSON` T-SQL function let you query json value. More information is available on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Let's you have this data :

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (ID int, x nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO @data
VALUES
    (1, ' {\"Indie_163\": \"A\","Pop_197\": null,\r\n  \"Mgr_206\": \"Mark Timberland\",\r\n  \"Date_225\": \"02/28/2019\",\r\n  \"Fees_200\": \"57500\"})'),
    (2, ' {\"Indie_163\": \"B\","Pop_197\": null,\r\n  \"Mgr_206\": \"Mark X\",\r\n  \"Date_225\": \"02/28/2017\",\r\n  \"Fees_200\": \"57501\"})'),
    (3, ' {\"Indie_164\": \"C\","Pop_197\": \"D\",\r\n  \"Mgr_206\": \"Mark Y\",\r\n  \"Date_225\": \"02/28/2018\",\r\n  \"Fees_200\": \"57502\"})')
```

[image]

You can query them by using

```
SELECT * 
FROM @data
    CROSS APPLY openjson(replace(replace(x, '\"', '"'), '\r\n', '')) x
```

Which will produce this

[image]

Then you can query each field you want like this :

```
SELECT id, 
    MAX(Pop_KEY)    POP_KEY,    MAX(Pop_VALUE)      Pop_VALUE,
    MAX(Indie_KEY)  Indie_KEY,  MAX(Indie_VALUE)    Indie_VALUE,
    MAX(Date_KEY)   Date_KEY,   MAX(Date_VALUE)     Date_VALUE,
    MAX(Fees_KEY)   Fees_KEY,   MAX(Fees_VALUE)     Fees_VALUE
FROM (
    SELECT id, 
        IIF(charindex('Pop',   [key]) = 1, [key],null) as Pop_KEY,   IIF( charindex('Pop',   [key]) = 1, [value],null) as Pop_VALUE,
        IIF(charindex('Indie', [key]) = 1, [key],null) as Indie_KEY, IIF( charindex('Indie', [key]) = 1, [value],null) as Indie_VALUE,
        IIF(charindex('Date',  [key]) = 1, [key],null) as Date_KEY,  IIF( charindex('Date',  [key]) = 1, [value],null) as Date_VALUE,
        IIF(charindex('Fees',  [key]) = 1, [key],null) as Fees_KEY,  IIF( charindex('Fees',  [key]) = 1, [value],null) as Fees_VALUE
    FROM @data
    CROSS APPLY openjson(replace(replace(x, '\"', '"'), '\r\n', '')) x 
) t
GROUP BY id
```

which will produce

[image]